# Node JS Webdriver - Resources to get started

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I'm looking for good resources about learning JavaScript for automation.

I am new to automation using NodeJs and webdriver. Whenever I search JavaScript tutorials, I get results that teach web development and not automation related topics.

I found tons of video tutorials for Selenium however only a handful for webdriver NodeJs.
So what should I learn in JavaScript to get along in webdriver NodeJs ?

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please review [How to Ask](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). It sounds like you are having trouble searching the internet for information about writing javascript for webdriver. Try browsing the [selenium-webdriver tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/selenium-webdriver) here on Stack Overflow to learn more about the topic. This will help you choose the right keywords for your web searches.

Comment: Rephrased, removed repetitions